# Why is the main file of my published npm package not accesible?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I published [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/real-men) pacakge to npm ([here](https://github.com/tavuntu/real-men)'s the GitHub repo) and, as you see, the main file in package.json is "men". It looks like I'm missing something because once I download it with `npm i -g real-men` and type `men` into the terminal (even after restarting the terminal and doing `source /etc/environment` ), I get a "men: command not found".

I see, for instance, that the "ng" executable for the Angular CLI has a link in the /bin node folder. Then I thought "hey, maybe I'm missing a step which copies a link to that folder", but I'm still confused and haven't found anything by googling it.

OS: Manjaro x64 (Illyria 18.0.0-rc)

Node: placed in user home folder (tar.gz extracted there, bin folder manually added to PATH)

npm -v: 6.4.1

node -v: v8.12.0

**EDIT**: I've marked as deprecated the package, by the time being

---

## Solved

Solved by adding this to package.json:

```
"bin": {
    "men": "./men"
 }
```

My bad, I was not aware of this property and its uses.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
npm install
```

You might have updated the file, but never actually downloaded the dependencies.

Comment: The dependencies of my package are OK, as well as the package.json (I checked in <node-folder>/lib/node_modules/ and everything's there, maybe you misunderstood the question?)